# jQuery current element with Babel Arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, babeljs

I try to implement Babel in my javascript application but I've got a problem with a particular syntax.

#### Old Javascript code = this refer to li current element

```
var li = $('<li/>').attr('role', 'presentation')
        .appendTo(navTabs).addClass( function() {
          if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {
            return 'active';
          }
        });
```

#### Babel code with arrow function = this is undefined

```
var li = $('<li/>').attr('role', 'presentation')
        .appendTo(navTabs).addClass( ()=> {
          if ($(this).is(':first-child')) {  // This is undefined
            return 'active';
          }
        });
```

How can I make this work with Babel arrow syntax ?

Comment: You can't. Just don't try to use an arrow function when you don't need one. There's nothing wrong with function expressions in ES6.

Comment: Hum okay, more complex than what I thought. Thank you.